# As you can see I am trying to create a link elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

```
<html>
  <head>
   <link 
 href="css/styles.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
   <body onload="createImg()">

    <h1>My Website</h1>

    <p>This is my first 
website</p>
    <div id='working_area' >
  
  
     </div>
 <script>
   function createImg(){

    var  img=document.getElementById("working_area");
img.innerHTML="<a src='https://www.google.com'>google</a>";
 }
 </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

So I want to create a hyperlink using this method and not using create elements method
**Why?**
Because I want to create a html editor

** **Is it possible ?****

Here is the image of results. The link doesn't working.
[image: this is the result I am getting]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `href` attribute rather than `src` for `a` tag.

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <link 
 href="css/styles.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
   <body onload="createImg()">

    <h1>My Website</h1>

    <p>This is my first 
website</p>
    <div id='working_area' >
  
  
     </div>
 <script>
   function createImg(){

    var  img=document.getElementById("working_area");
img.innerHTML="<a href='https://www.google.com'>google</a>";
 }
 </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In HTML the `<a>` tag defines a hyperlink and the `<href>` attribute indicates the link destination. `<src>` is not part of it.